# Is the Yoneda embedding part of a larger structure?

Tags: category-theory

The Yoneda embedding for a category $A$ embeds it in its category of presheaves $\hat{A}:=Set^{A^{op}}$ as $y_A:A \rightarrow \hat{A}$. This makes it look as though it should be part of larger 'structure' - perhaps the component of some natural transformation, except here the arrow is between categories rather than functors. But if we use the identity functor for $Cat$, that is $1_{Cat}$, then we can rewrite the the first term as $A=1_{cat}A$ but the second term doesn't appear to re-writable in the same way.

So can we have a functor $y:Cat\rightarrow Cat$ such that $y(A)=y_A$ and for a functor $F:A\rightarrow B$, we have $y(F):y_A \rightarrow y_B$?

Is this even the right way to think about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can characterize the Yoneda functor $y\colon\mathcal C\to \widehat{\cal C}$ as a *free cocompletion* operation.

In a few words [and size issues apart: from now on everything happens in a universe of sets; maybe some of you can correct my lack of detail], you are considering a left adjoint to a functor which regards cocomplete categories as a sub(2-)category of all categories, which starts from $\cal C$ and enlarges it until it added *all* possible colimits for *all* possible shape of diagrams.

In a much more conceptual way, you are looking for something which gives you an equivalence of categories between $\mathbf{Funct}({\cal C,D})$ and $\mathbf{Cocont}({\widehat{\cal C},\cal D})$ for any cocomplete category $\cal D$; or in other words, you are looking for a procedure which exhibits a category $\widehat{\cal C}$ out of $\cal C$, such that any $F\colon\cal C\to $ {cocomplete} extends *uniquely* to a cocontinuous functor $\hat F\colon \widehat{\cal C}\to ${cocomplete}.

I can give you more details about how to build $\hat F$, but I think they could confuse you if you lack a couple of prerequisites; so tell me if you'd rather digest this, first :)

Another interesting point is that this is an "extremist" way to add colimits; you can add things little by little and yet continue to live happy! For example you can fix a prescribed class of limits, say $\mathcal J\subset\mathbf{Cat}$ and consider a functor $\mathsf{Ind}_\cal J$ which adds *only* $\cal J$-shaped colimit; for example if $\cal J$ contains only the empty category, your empty-completed $\cal C$ contains an initial object. If $\cal J$ contains the discrete category $\{0,1\}$, then $\mathsf{Ind}_\cal J(\cal C)$ has finite coproducts...

This point of view opens another Pandora's box; I suggest you to google some keywords like "ind-completion", "presentable and accessible category".

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, the Yoneda operation can be understood as a right adjoint - or rather as part of an equivalence? It would be useful to have some more detail - where is this spelt out?

Comment: No. sorry if I have been a little sketchy. Your free cocompletion is a left adjoint ("free" things are always "lefty", even if it's far from accurate politically speaking). The canonical way to extend your $F$ is given by the Yoneda extension of $F$, namely the left Kan extension of $F$ along the Yoneda embedding.

Comment: Thanks for the explication, and also for the mnemonic.

Comment: You're welcome! On the same vein, Lawvere called "fascist" the right adjoint to a forgetful functor, but this poetic (?) denomination never became popular... More on your question: there is an entire section in Ademek-Rosicki "Locally presentable categories" which gives you a fairly good introduction to this, proving explicitly the results I stated. Despite the fact that it is fairly natural, the question "how can I complete with respect to a prescribed class of diagrams?" has been adressed only recently: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.28.3481&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf{Cat}$ denote the category of small categories, $\mathbf{Cat}_{LS}$ denote the category of locally small categories(see Remark 1). There exists an obvious inclusion functor $V\colon \mathbf{Cat}\to\mathbf{Cat}_{LS}$(which sends $A$ to $A$, because every small category is locally small). Then denote by $D\colon\mathbf{Cat}\to\mathbf{Cat}$ the *dualization functor*, such that $D(A)=A^{op}$ and $D(T)=T^{op}$. Also we can construct the *generalized inverse image functor* $R\colon\mathbf{Cat}^{op}\to\mathbf{Cat}_{LS}$, such that $R(A)=\mathbf{Set}^{A}$ and $R(T)=T^*$(see Remark 2). Then we can consider a composition:
$$
\mathbf{Cat}^{op}\xrightarrow{D^{op}}\mathbf{Cat}^{op}\xrightarrow{R}\mathbf{Cat}_{LS}
$$
The functor $R\circ D^{op}$ sends $A$ to $\mathbf{Set}^{A^{op}}$, as you wanted. But we can't consider the Yoneda embedding as a natural transformation $V\to R\circ D^{op}$, because the first functor is from $\mathbf{Cat}$, but the second is from $\mathbf{Cat}^{op}$.

**Remark 1.** One can rightly note, that actually $\mathbf{Cat}_{LS}$ is not a category in the usual sense(because its objects don't form a class). But we can consider $\mathbf{Cat}_{LS}$ as a metacategory(see [MacLane, CWFM, 1 chapter] for the reference).

**Remark 2.** Let $A$ and $B$ be categories, $T\colon A\to B$ be a functor between them. Then we can define the *inverse image functor* $T^*\colon\mathbf{Set}^{B}\to\mathbf{Set}^A$, such that:
$$
T^*(S)=S\circ T;
$$
$$
(T^*(\alpha))(a)=\alpha(T(a)),
$$
for any $S\colon B\to\mathbf{Set}$ and any $\alpha\colon S\to S'$(where $S,S'\colon B\to\mathbf{Set}$). It is an easy exercise to check that $T^*(\alpha)$ is indeed a natural transformation and $T^*$ is indeed a functor.

Comment: извините @Oskar, but your "category of locally small categories"... does not exist, since the collection of locally small categories is too large to form a class, hence it cannot be the object class of any category. Indeed, if you notice, it is prominently absent in all mayor CT textbooks, from CWM onwards. Maybe your argument may be restated in another form.

Comment: @magma Thanks for a comment. I am not a specialist in the foundations, but I don't think that size issues affect this reasoning. Firstly, I can replace "category of all localy small categories" on "metacategory of all locally small categories". Secondly, to talk about the considered functor, we can take a category with class of objects $\{\mathbf{Set}^{A^{op}}|\;A\;\text{- small}\}\cup\{A|\;A\;\text{- small}\}$. If you think that it would be more correct, I will make appropriate corrections.

Comment: Leaving aside for a moment the question of size, could you please explain what is it that you mean by $T^*$ ?

Comment: @magma Of course, I had to include it. Thanks.